# CSS webkit animation causes flicker

Tags: css, animation, webkit, flicker

i have a css animation with 10 images. it works perfect, 
but if i make the browser larger or smaller(ctrl +, ctrl -), than it flickers.

```
-webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/

how can i optimize my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its how to chrome manage the sprite, you can call it a bug. After zoom in or zoom out the positioning get mismatched but reload at same zoom level it will work agian